# Regex to get last three folders

Tags: regex, url

Trying to get the last three folders in a path regardless of how many folders are in a path.

As a further compounding factor this needs to only match if the first folder is a certain string.

I have this but it uses 5 groups and only supports at max 5 folders.

```
/(a)/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)/$
```

Need to get

```
/a/
$1 = a
$2 = 
$3 = 

/a/b/
$1 = a
$2 = b 
$3 = 

/a/b/c/
$1 = a
$2 = b
$3 = c

/a/b/c/d/
$1 = b
$2 = c
$3 = d

/a/b/c/d/e/
$1 = c
$2 = d
$3 = e

/b/c/d/e/
Not a Match because first folder is not "a"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/a.*/(\w*?)/(\w*?)/(\w*?)/|/(a)/(?:(\w+?)/)?(\w+?)?
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xX5zW3/1)**

[image]

```
MATCH 1
4.  [1-2]   `a`
MATCH 2
4.  [5-6]   `a`
5.  [7-8]   `b`
MATCH 3
4.  [11-12] `a`
5.  [13-14] `b`
6.  [15-16] `c`
MATCH 4
1.  [21-22] `b`
2.  [23-24] `c`
3.  [25-26] `d`
MATCH 5
1.  [33-34] `c`
2.  [35-36] `d`
3.  [37-38] `e`
```

I think there should be a better regex to do this but you could go with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    (?!^\/[b-z])^.*?\/?(\w)?\/?(\w)?\/(\w)\/$
```

This checks if the string start with "a" via lookahead.Rest will follow.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lK9iD2/9

Comment: This will match `/0/b/c/d/e/`. Why are you using a negative lookahead instead of a simple `/a`?